# Ubuntu changed to startx

Tags: tty, i3-window-manager

Hello i switched from the standard graphical interface of ubuntu to boot into a tty so now i have to start i3 with `startx` instead of using the graphical one.
But now i have some issues:
Im using rofi as my program launcher and before it was nice and sorted by the amount i opened the program (opened more often = top) but now the list got reset (every program is at 0 again) and some of my programs dont show (like spotify)
Also my notification manager (dunst) doesnt work anymore (i can still do `notify-send "test"` but for example discord doesnt show my notifications anymore)

Can anyone please help me fix this issue?
I dont really understand why there are these problems now.
I just changed from the graphical login to tty (`startx`)

.xinitrc :

```
exec i3
```

ubuntu version: 20.04.3
i changed to the tty by changing
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in my /etc/default/grub to "text" instead of "quiet splash"

Answer (score 1):

I changed my `.xinitrc` from

```
exec i3
```

to

```
#!/bin/sh
eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)
exec i3
```